# Why is the "IsPost" and "AsPost" underlined red?

Tags: c#, html, razor, razor-pages

Im trying to program a database query, but there is always that red line below "IsPost" an "AsPost".
What do I need to do to get it working?

Thanks for your help :)

```
@page
@model AboutModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Datenverzeichnis";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<form method="post">
@{
if (IsPost)
{
    string materialnumber = Request.Form["materialnumber"];
    int serialnumber = Request.Form["serialnumber"].AsInt();
    <text>
        You entered: <br />
        Material Number: @materialnumber <br />
        Serial Number: @serialnumber <br />
    </text>
}
}
<p>
<div>
    <label for="text">Materialnummer</label>
    <input type="text" id="matn">
    <label for="text">ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="id">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Bestätigen" class="submit" />
    <button type="button" id="clear" 
onclick="document.getElementById('matn').value = '';

document.getElementById('id').value = ''">
        Löschen
    </button>
</div>
</p>

@{
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">MaterialNumber</td>
        <td width="5%">SerialNumber</td>
        <td width="10%">Source</td>
        <td width="30%">Name</td>
        <td width="10%">Status</td>
        <td width="20%">URL</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @{
        foreach (var deviceInfo in Model.DeviceInfos)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@deviceInfo.MaterialNumber</td>
                <td>@deviceInfo.SerialNumber</td>
                <td>@deviceInfo.Source</td>
                <td>@deviceInfo.Name</td>
                <td>@deviceInfo.Status</td>
                <td>@deviceInfo.Url</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
</table>
}
</form>
```

> That is the updated version with the whole code. I hope that you can figure it out this way.
>   "CS0103 C# The name does not exist in the current context" that is the shown error code.

Comment: What is IsPost, did you define it?

Comment: You first use the IsPost method to determine whether the page is being posted — that is, whether a user clicked the Submit button. If this is a post, IsPost returns true

Comment: But where you declare the IsPost method? In your "if" condition IsPost is used like a variable. I think you get confused because windows forms has a IsPostBack property.

Comment: @TiagoCrizanto https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.helperpage.ispost?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2

Comment: Considering @Crowcoder comment, maybe your application don't reference System.Web.WebPages.dll. Check if yout project has this refence. If this don't work try add complete namespace System.Web.WebPages.IsPost

Comment: I think the issue is not found in the part of code/html shown now.

Comment: Usually you would check if the request is POST in the controller.  Why do you need to know that it's a POST in the view?

Comment: So what do you want me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you want to know if the request is a POST in the actual view. You could use `HttpContext.Request.Method`.  The below code may work for you:

```
    if (this.Context.Request.Method == "POST")
    {
        string materialnumber = this.Context.Request.Form["materialnumber"];
        string serialnumber = this.Context.Request.Form["serialnumber"];
        <text>
            You entered: <br />
            Material Number: @materialnumber <br />
            Serial Number: @serialnumber <br />
        </text>
    }
```

Another approach would be to set a value in the controller when it is posted.  Something like this might work:

```
[HttpPost]        // --> this is a POST request
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    ViewBag.IsPost = true;

    return View();
}
```

Then in your view:

```
if (ViewBag.IsPost)
{
    string materialnumber = Request.Form["materialnumber"];
    string serialnumber = Request.Form["serialnumber"];
    <text>
        You entered: <br />
        Material Number: @materialnumber <br />
        Serial Number: @serialnumber <br />
    </text>
}
```